# Get-AzureADExtensionProperty cmd-let doesnt give any output

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a collection that contains the extension properties registered with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) through Azure AD Connect. I am using azure powershell command --> `Get-AzureADExtensionProperty -IsSyncedFromOnPremises $True`. And this command doesnt give me any output, I should get a list of properties, I know that these properties exists. in order to connect to azure AD I am using standard powershell command --> `connect-azuread`. I am connecting from my local laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command get extension properties synced from the on-premises AD with `-IsSyncedFromOnPremises $True`, make sure you have synced them from your on-premises Active Directory to Azure AD.

Try to use Azure AD Connect to sync again, make sure you select the `Directory extension attribute sync` option.

Reference - [**Sync an attribute from your on-premises Active Directory to Azure AD**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/user-provisioning-sync-attributes-for-mapping)